# How to install KDE 5.2 or 5.3 in Linux Mint 17.1 KDE

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kde, kde-plasma-workspace

I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon/kf5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install project-neon5-session project-neon5-utils project-neon5-konsole project-neon5-breeze project-neon5-plasma-workspace-wallpapers
```

but I get this error:

```
No JSON object could be decoded
```

How can I install KDE 5.2 or 5.3 on Linux Mint 17.1 KDE?

Comment: Did you install kde plasma 5 using this ppa? Have you been facing any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they changed the name of their PPA.  Try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon/ppa
```

[Project Neon](https://launchpad.net/~neon/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

As stated on their site: "FOR LOVE OF BLUE GEARS! PACKAGES HERE ARE UNSTABLE, USE AT YOUR OWN RISK"

Comment: Have you installed kde plasma 5 using this ppa? Have you been facing any issues?

Comment: @lovesh I haven't installed it because it is unstable. I am waiting for a Linux Mint Official OS upgrade ;)